# Finding an element with max. no of appearing in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I have the following table:

id    |    year

10    |    2000

11    |    2001

10    |    2002

12    |    2003

11    |    2004

13    |    2005

10    |    2006

10    |    2007

According to id, since 10 appears most, the selection should give 10 for this table. I know this is easy but I couldn't go further than COUNT(*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following SQL will work when there is more then one id having the maximum count:

```
SELECT id FROM table GROUP BY 1 
HAVING COUNT(*)=( SELECT MAX(t.count) 
                    FROM ( SELECT id,COUNT(*) AS count
                             FROM table GROUP BY 1 ) t )
```

The first (innermost) `SELECT` will just count each id, this is used in the second `SELECT` to determine the maximum count and this will be used in the final (outermost) `SELECT` to display only the right IDs.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You need a group by, order by - along with a limit:

```
SELECT id FROM sometable GROUP BY id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1
```

This will group the table by id, order them in descending order by their count and pick the first row (the one with highest count).

Comment: since there can be more than one highest count with same count of course, picking first row may not be enough.

Comment: Yeah I hadn't realised that was of concern based off of the question - I see someone already posted the answer for that problem - although I'm not sure that the posted query is not overly complex.